# FFmpeg screencast: capture only one window

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming, screen-capture, screencasts

I'm using FFmpeg with UScreenCapture under Windows 7 for screencast. Everything works fine, but I want to stream video from only one window - not the whole monitor. I know, there is an opportunity to cut a window's area with `-vf crop w:h:x:y` command with FFmpeg, but this will work only until the window is moved or resized. Is there a normal solution of this problem?

Comment: The best solution is using screen capture software that can capture only a selected window. Don't waste your time by trying FFmpeg to do that for you, since the window can be on different locations. Maybe [Windows screen capture recorder to video](https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free) is a solution for you?

Comment: You did not take a look at the site I provided, that software creates a DirectShow source and that site has also decent FFmpeg examples which you can use.